# Inserting fast clickable titles in bibliography websites (master thesis)

Tags: bibtex, hyperlink

I am writing my thesis and I have a doubt on the bibliography. I am using Bibtex, with a unique document.bib where I put all the information. When I cite a website I use the format @misc, and I enter normally the URL and all the data. My objective would be to obtain an output where by clicking on the title of the site,a hyperlink to the site is created

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Such functionality depends on your setup since there are various different ways to create a bibliography. However, the `hyperref` package provides basic functionality for this and automatically turns `\url`s into interactive links. If you want more specific help, consider providing a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The solution that you proposed is actually what I am doing now, by inserting the clickable URL. My objective is to avoid to put the URL (that sometimes is pretty long), and to put like a representative title of the site, where you can click and go to the site directly